# Changing QLabel on a push of a button each time its pressed it's overwrited

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlabel, qpushbutton

I want to print out the average of a set of 3 numbers the user inputs. However ever time I push the button the text overlaps eachother

```py
def Comp
    Average = QtGui.QLabel("The Students Average is " + str(self.average), self)
    Average.move(400,300)
    Average.setFont(QtGui.QFont('sanSerif',16))
    Average.resize(Average.sizeHint())
    Average.show()

btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Test",self)
btn.clicked.connect(self.comp)
```

any sort of help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new QLabel each time you press the button, instead you must reuse the QLabel.

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.average_label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.average_label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("sanSerif", 16))
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Test")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.average_label)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        import random
        self.average = random.uniform(0, 100) # emulate average
        self.average_label.setText(
            "The Students Average is {}".format(self.average)
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```